# Why the height of container not adapt when the height of its image content has changed?

Tags: html, css

When I set the height of image to 50%,its container's height stay the same instead of automatically adapt.

HTML:

```
<section class="img-show">

        <div class="img-container">
            <ul>
                <li class="img-item">
                    <a href="">
                        <img src="./AnimatedFrameSlideshow_Featured.jpg" alt="">
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="img-item">
                    <a href="">
                        <img src="./DecorativeLetterEffects_featured.jpg" alt="">
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>
```

CSS:

```
.img-show {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.img-container {
    width: 400%;
}
.img-show ul {
    display: flex;
    padding: 0;
}
.img-item {
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
}
.img-item img {
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
}
```

After these code, **img** has changed its height to 50%,but the height of **img-show** stay the same and the blank content has filled in half.

Maybe the question is ambiguous,but any help will be welcome.Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `.img-item a { display: block; }` ?

Answer (score 2):

If you img height is 50% of its parent, then its container must be twice as high as the img. Hence the lower half of the container must be blank content.

In essence, the container is defined in terms of its contents height. So if the image  height was defined in terms of its container height, this would be a circular definition. To resolve this, the browser uses the width of the image together with the intrinsic aspect ratio of the image to determine the 100% height of image, and then adjusts the image height to be the specified percentage of that height. No matter what the specified percentage is, the container height will inevitably be the 100% height of the image.

Comment: How can I  remove the blank content,i.e. to make the height of container equals to img's height by using percentage?

Comment: Maybe my question is unclear.I mean how to make the height of img-container adapt to the height of img.When I set the height of container by using percentage,it is stay the same.

Comment: Your question is clear. I'm not convinced it can be done with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what is what you expect from your code, but according to the img [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp) both height and width of an `img` tag should be set directly in the tag. so imagine you want an 50x50 image, you would do something like this:

`<img alt="" height="50" width="50" />`

Hope it is useful

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Maybe you misunderstand my question.I have no idea to make the height of container equal to img's height by using percentage.

Comment: You don't have to, it is normally a bad practice to set any height in the css, if the image has the correct height in the `img` tag, the div containing the image will adapt without setting any height in the css